# Source with `publishReplay()` and `refCount()` doesn't work as expected between subscriptions in multiple components in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to figure out how `publishReplay` in rxjs works. I have an example where it works as expected:

```
const source = new Subject()
const sourceWrapper = source.pipe(
  publishReplay(1),
  refCount()
)

const subscribeTest1 = sourceWrapper
.subscribe(
  (data: any) => {
    console.log('subscriber1 received a value:', data)
  }
)

source.next(1)
source.next(2)

setTimeout(() => {
  const subscribeTest2 = sourceWrapper
  .subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      console.log('subscriber2 received a value:', data)
    }
  )
}, 5000)
```

We have a subject and a wrapper on it where `publushReplay(1), refCount()` are added.
We create first subscription and then emit 2 values. As a result, we see in console the following:

```
subscriber1 received a value: 1
subscriber1 received a value: 2
```

And after 5 seconds we create another subscription, which receives last buffered value from `ReplaySubject` created by `publishReplay(1)`. As a result, we will see one more note in console after 5 seconds:

```
subscriber2 received a value: 2
```

[Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-working-example-of-publishreplay)

So far so good.

But I have another example, where I try to apply this pattern in Angular application. [Here is the link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-publishreplay-between-components-test).

It contains a single module with 2 components `app.component.ts` and `hello.component.ts` and 1 service `test.service.ts`

**test.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TestService {
  private _test$: Subject<string> = new Subject()

  public get test$(): Observable<string> {
    return this._test$.pipe(
      publishReplay(1),
      refCount()
    )
  }

  public pushToStream(val: string): void {
    this._test$.next(val)
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testService.test$.subscribe((data: string) => {
      console.log('Subscriber in app.component received a value: ', data)
    })
    this.testService.pushToStream('new value')
    this.testService.pushToStream('one more value')
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(private testService: TestService) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.testService.test$.subscribe((data: string) => {
        console.log('Subscriber in hello component received a value:', data)
      })
    }, 4000)
  }

}
```

Here is the same principle: hold source in service, which is the singleton, create 1 subscription in `app.component.ts`, emit 2 values and create another subscription with the delay in `hello.component.ts`. As we could see in the previous example, the second subscription should get latest buffered value, but it doesn't. We only see in console the following:

```
Subscriber in app.component received a value: new value
Subscriber in app.component received a value: one more value
```

What am I missing out and why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the wrapper reference to the subject is lost when returned using an accessor (getter) or a member function (eg. `getTest() { return this.test$ }`). If the value `test$` is declared `public` and accessed directly, the reference to the source observable seems to be preserved among different components. Try the following

Service

```js
export class TestService {
  private _test$: Subject<string> = new Subject()

  public test$ = this._test$.pipe(
    publishReplay(1),
    refCount()
  );

  public pushToStream(val: string): void {
    this._test$.next(val)
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-publishreplay-between-components-test-ggxrfz)

Probably the functions return separate copies of the variables that are bound to the same subject observable but they (the individual `test$` in the components) isn't the same instance but multiple individual instances.

Perhaps someone else might be able to provide a canonical answer.